# UIView bottom part is not clickable

Tags: ios, objective-c, uiview, uibutton

I am having this weird issue which is driving me nut for the last couple of days. Tried various things and tricks suggested in the forum but no luck so far. Basically I have tabbarview controller with a tableview when user clicks on the table row it takes to the detail screen. I have four fixed buttons at the bottom of this screen but these buttons are not clickable or does not recognise the touches. I guess it is to do with mainscreen size or applicationview frame. If I place the buttons at about CGRectMake(0,330,320,50) that means leave around 50 clear space at the bottom then they work. Here is the related code for this issue -

```
//Bottom fixed Bar and Buttons//
self.edgesForExtendedLayout=UIRectEdgeNone;

UIImageView *lineImg=[[UIImageView alloc]init];
//lineImg.frame=CGRectMake(0, 748, 320, 2);
[lineImg setBackgroundColor:[UIColor colorWithRed:0.9058 green:0.4705 blue:0 alpha:1.0]];
[self.view addSubview:lineImg];

  addFavBtn=[UIButton buttonWithType:UIButtonTypeCustom];
[addFavBtn setBackgroundColor:[UIColor colorWithRed:0.0392 green:0.1686 blue:0.2196 alpha:1.0]];
[addFavBtn setTitle:@"Add Fav" forState:UIControlStateNormal];
[addFavBtn setTitleColor:[UIColor whiteColor] forState:UIControlStateNormal];
addFavBtn.titleLabel.textAlignment=NSTextAlignmentCenter;
addFavBtn.titleLabel.font=[UIFont fontWithName:@"MyriadPro-Regular" size:20];
[addFavBtn addTarget:self action:@selector(addFavBtnClick) forControlEvents:UIControlEventTouchUpInside];
[self.view addSubview:addFavBtn];
addFavBtn.userInteractionEnabled=YES;



UIImageView *lineImg1=[[UIImageView alloc]init];
//lineImg1.frame=CGRectMake(80, 750, 1, 35);
[lineImg1 setBackgroundColor:[UIColor whiteColor]];
[self.view addSubview:lineImg1];

shareBtn=[UIButton buttonWithType:UIButtonTypeCustom];
//shareBtn.frame=CGRectMake(81, 750, 79, 35);
[shareBtn setBackgroundColor:[UIColor colorWithRed:0.0392 green:0.1686 blue:0.2196 alpha:1.0]];
[shareBtn setTitle:@"Share" forState:UIControlStateNormal];
[shareBtn setTitleColor:[UIColor whiteColor] forState:UIControlStateNormal];
shareBtn.titleLabel.textAlignment=NSTextAlignmentCenter;
shareBtn.titleLabel.font=[UIFont fontWithName:@"MyriadPro-Regular" size:20];
[shareBtn addTarget:self action:@selector(shareBtnClick:) forControlEvents:UIControlEventTouchUpInside];
[self.view addSubview:shareBtn];

UIImageView *lineImg2=[[UIImageView alloc]init];
//lineImg2.frame=CGRectMake(160, 748, 1, 35);
[lineImg2 setBackgroundColor:[UIColor whiteColor]];
[self.view addSubview:lineImg2];


reviewBtn=[UIButton buttonWithType:UIButtonTypeCustom];
//reviewBtn.frame=CGRectMake(161, 750, 79, 35);
[reviewBtn setBackgroundColor:[UIColor colorWithRed:0.0392 green:0.1686 blue:0.2196 alpha:1.0]];
[reviewBtn setTitle:@"Review" forState:UIControlStateNormal];
[reviewBtn setTitleColor:[UIColor whiteColor] forState:UIControlStateNormal];
reviewBtn.titleLabel.textAlignment=NSTextAlignmentCenter;
reviewBtn.titleLabel.font=[UIFont fontWithName:@"MyriadPro-Regular" size:20];
[reviewBtn addTarget:self action:@selector(reviewBtnClick) forControlEvents:UIControlEventTouchUpInside];
[self.view addSubview:reviewBtn];

UIImageView *lineImg3=[[UIImageView alloc]init];
// lineImg3.frame=CGRectMake(240, 750, 1, 35);
[lineImg3 setBackgroundColor:[UIColor whiteColor]];
[self.view addSubview:lineImg3];

helpBtn=[UIButton buttonWithType:UIButtonTypeCustom];
//helpBtn.frame=CGRectMake(241, 750, 79, 35);
[helpBtn setBackgroundColor:[UIColor colorWithRed:0.0392 green:0.1686 blue:0.2196 alpha:1.0]];
[helpBtn setTitle:@"Help" forState:UIControlStateNormal];
[helpBtn setTitleColor:[UIColor whiteColor] forState:UIControlStateNormal];
helpBtn.titleLabel.textAlignment=NSTextAlignmentCenter;
helpBtn.titleLabel.font=[UIFont fontWithName:@"MyriadPro-Regular" size:20];
[helpBtn addTarget:self action:@selector(helpViewBtnClick) forControlEvents:UIControlEventTouchUpInside];
[self.view addSubview:helpBtn];

UIImageView *lineImgLast=[[UIImageView alloc]init];
//lineImgLast.frame=CGRectMake(0, 748, 320, 2);
[lineImgLast setBackgroundColor:[UIColor colorWithRed:0.0392 green:0.1686 blue:0.2196 alpha:1.0]];
[self.view addSubview:lineImgLast];



imageNameDetailArray=[[NSMutableArray alloc]init];
parkListDetailArray=[[NSMutableArray alloc]init];
parkListViseDetailArray=[[NSMutableArray alloc]init];

self.responseData=[NSMutableData data];


//get the size of the screen
CGSize result = [[UIScreen mainScreen] bounds].size; //to see the actual screen size - returns 568
CGSize frame = [[UIScreen mainScreen] applicationFrame].size; //to see the application frame size - returns 548
 //UIScreen *screen = [UIScreen mainScreen];
//CGRect fullScreenRect = screen.bounds;

[self.view setAutoresizingMask:UIViewAutoresizingFlexibleHeight];

NSLog(@"mainscreen size - %f",result.height);
NSLog(@"Application frame size - %f",frame.height);

int newSize=cs+50;
int fBar=result.height-50;

homeBg.frame=CGRectMake(0,0, 320, result.height);

//set the height of the scroller view
parkViewScrollView.frame=CGRectMake(0, 63, 320, result.height-128);
parkViewScrollView.contentSize=CGSizeMake(320, newSize);


lineImg.frame=CGRectMake(0, fBar, 320, 2);
addFavBtn.frame=CGRectMake(0, fBar+2, 79, 48);
lineImg1.frame=CGRectMake(80, fBar+2, 1, 48);
shareBtn.frame=CGRectMake(81, fBar+2, 79, 48);
lineImg2.frame=CGRectMake(160, fBar+2, 1, 48);
reviewBtn.frame=CGRectMake(161, fBar+2, 79, 48);
lineImg3.frame=CGRectMake(240, fBar+2, 1, 48);
helpBtn.frame=CGRectMake(241, fBar+2, 79, 48);
```

https://i.stack.imgur.com/kOp9P.png

Comment: Are those buttons you show in your linked image covering up the tab bar controller's tabs? If so, how did you get them to not be behind the tabs?

Comment: Have you tried bringing your button views to front of main view?

Comment: Thanks for your reply, i have tried this but no luck. There is no tabbar view in the detailview - `code` [self.view bringSubviewToFront:addFavBtn];
    [self.view bringSubviewToFront:shareBtn];
    [self.view bringSubviewToFront:reviewBtn];
    [self.view bringSubviewToFront:helpBtn]; `code`

Comment: actually i realised I was hiding the tabbarview using  self.tabBarController.tabBar.hidden=YES; but I cannot still use this bottom tabbar area.

Comment: Are you placing the buttons inside scrollview? If so instead of adding buttons to a view try directly adding the buttons to scrollview as it might be issue with view size and scrollview content size. BTW which xcode version are you using and are you checking this in ios 7? If you are using autolayout try turning it off.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks everyone for responding. Interestingly even though the tabbar was hidden still I could not use that reserved space for buttons. I have used the following line before the pushing the details view controller. This seems to be working fine and I can now click all buttons.

```
//this one line of code did the trick after spending hours of time
```

objDetailView.hidesBottomBarWhenPushed=YES;
    [self.navigationController pushViewController:objDetailView animated:YES];